# ¿Es una buena práctica de programación esta comunicación entre clases?

Tags: java, hilos, patrones-de-diseño

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio en Java y tengo una duda sobre si estoy llevando a cabo una buena práctica o es desaconsejable lo que estoy haciendo.Explicaré mi problema con clases de ejemplo para simplificar el código.
Tengo una interfaz Observador, y dos clases, Nucleo y OtraClase. Nucleo implementa Observador y tiene un atributo OtraClase, y OtraClase tiene como atributo un Observador para llamar a sus méodos cuando quiera notificar un evento a Nucleo. Es similar al patrón MVC pero sin controlador.

Por un lado la interfaz Observador:

```
     public class Observador {
         public void mensajeRecibido(String mensaje);
     }
```

Por otro lado la clase OtraClase:

```
    public class OtraClase {
        private Observer observador;

        public OtraClase(Observador observador){
            this.observador = observador;
        }

        public void pedirDato(){ 
            Thread hilo = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    observador.mensajeRecibido("nuevoMensaje");
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Por otro lado la clase Nucleo.

```
     public class Nucleo implements Observador {
         private OtraClase otraClase;

         private String mensaje;

         public Nucleo(){
             this.otraClase = new OtraClase(this);
         }

         public void pedirDato(){
             otraClase.pedirDato();
             wait();
             System.out.println("Mensaje actualizado");
         }

         @Override
         public synchronized void mensajeRecibido(String mensaje){
             this.mensaje = mensaje;
             notify();
         }
    }
```

Como el método que se llama en OtraClase se delega a un hilo no puedo devolver de inmediato un valor a Nucleo sino que dejo a éste durmiendo con wait() y es el método de Observador quien lo despierta con notify().

Me gustaría saber si esto no es recomendable por alguna razón o si es una buena práctica.

Asimismo me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de esperar dentro del método de OtraClase y asi poder devolver el valor con un return. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Veo algunos problemitas que quisiera comentar, pero a la vez, no estoy seguro que el código en la pregunta represente bien la realidad de tu problema. Por ejemplo, la interfaz no está definido correctamente, el `wait()` ocurre fuera de un bloque synchronized, etc.  Y por los comentarios que dejastes mas abajo, parece que lo del `Thread` tal vez no funcione como se ve en la pregunta. Si hay manera de que el ejemplo sea válido y aproxime más la realidad, y donde quede claro cuales areas puedes o no puedes modificar, ¡eso sería genial!

Answer (score 1):

En este caso particular no es buena practica de comunicar así entre los objetos.

En el método *pedirDato()* de tu *Nucleo* tu siempre esperas hasta que tienes un resultado. Tomando eso en cuanta podrías perfectamente procesar el código del otro objeto en la misma hebra. Construir una nueva hebra para eso es costoso para la maquina virtual y no te da ningún beneficio aquí.

en *Nucleo*:

```
public void pedirDato(){
    this.mensaje = otraClase.pedirDato();
}
```

y en *OtraClase*:

```
public String pedirDato(){
    String dato;
    // codigo para generar dato
    return dato;
}
```

te da el mismo resultado.

Ahora, si se trata de tener un calculo costoso en *pedirDato()* de *OtraClase*, el código funciona pero no necesariamente es buena practica por los siguientes razones:

1) El código en *Nucleo* no funciona así. El método *notify()* tira una InterruptedException en el método bloqueando ( *wait()* ). Así se necesita el siguiente código:

```
public synchronized void pedirDato(){
        try{
            otraClase.pedirDato();
            wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            // hebra notificado
        }
        // resultado disponible
}
```

Además se debería considerar usar un *ThreadPool* ([en oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)) o un *Scheduler* para trabajos así, como por ejemplo *java.util.Timer* con *java.util.TimerTask*. Normalmente no vale la pena de crear una propia implementación de un *ThreadPool*, los que ya existen funcionan bastante bien para tareas asincrónicos.

Comment: El problema es que en mi programa real la llamada a OtraClase usa una librería que procesa una función en otro hilo y no puedo cambiar eso. Lo del hilo no se puede cambiar.

Comment: Para no confundirme, puedes aclarar que de los artefactos son bajo tu control y cuales son parte de la biblioteca? Entiendo bien que _OtraClase_ representa una clase de una biblioteca que te devuelve el resultado en su propia hebra?

Comment: OtraClase está hecha por mí pero para devolver un resultado pedido por Núcleo llama a un metodo de una librería que funciona como un nuevo hilo y no se puede saber cuando acabará esta llamada

Comment: Ok, entonces _Nucleo_ y _OtraClase_ son tuyos y la biblioteca se llama cuando se genera la respuesta en _otra.Clase.pedirDato()_.
Voy a seguir explicando con eso.